# How to count rows in a column between two rows containing specific text in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I am using PowerBI desktop. I have a table column which has a lot of rows (all string values). I need to count the number of rows between two specific rows. Text in these two specific rows are static.

Comment: Are the static text rows unique?

Comment: Yes, they are unique. Basically a line of text that will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a table that I call `myTable` which holds the example data for this answer. The values in `column1` corresponds to your unique static strings.

| column1 |
| --- |
| record5 |
| record8 |
| record4 |
| record3 |
| record1 |
| record2 |
| record7 |
| record6 |
| record9 |

Start by going to powerquery and add an Index column like this:

```
let
   <my example table, but you should have your data here>,
   #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
in
   #"Added Index"
```

The table now looks like this:

| column1 | Index |
| --- | --- |
| record5 | 0 |
| record8 | 1 |
| record4 | 2 |
| record3 | 3 |
| record1 | 4 |
| record2 | 5 |
| record7 | 6 |
| record6 | 7 |
| record9 | 8 |

After this, go to the Data View and create three measures.

1. `Measure1` holds the Index value of the row you want to start counting from
2. `Measure2` holds the Index value of the row you want to stop counting at
3. `Measure3` is simply `Measure2 - Measure3 - 1`

I've decided to count the number of rows between the rows with values `record8` and `record2`. This what the Measures looks like:

```
Measure1 = CALCULATE(VALUES(myTable[Index]), myTable[column1] = "record8")
```

```
Measure2 = CALCULATE(VALUES(myTable[Index]), myTable[column1] = "record2")
```

```
Measure3 = myTable[Measure2] - myTable[Measure1] - 1
```

The value of `Measure3` is now `3` which is the number of rows between the row with value `record8` and the row with value `record2`.

Note that this only works as long as the static strings are 100% unique.

Comment: Now when I have the difference count displayed in digits, could you also please suggest how to display the content of the rows. For ex if the difference count is 5, I want to extract those five rows in a different table

Comment: sir, if you could plz suggest something. TIA

Comment: That's a separate question in it self so won't have space enough to answer it here in much detail. But I think a step in the right direction is if you'd create a calculated table using the same data and then using the FILTER function in dax to exclude all rows that you don't want.

Comment: Also, if my answer to your question worked for the initial qustion you had, please mark ut as accepted answer, Thanks :)

Comment: Hey wenzell. It was definitely a great help. Its working now. I have marked your answer. Many thanks again.